# How to open an image from a shared folder with authentication?

Tags: c#, image, .net-4.0, file-sharing

I was trying to open an image from a file folder with authentication using the `Image.FromFile` method but an error is occurring when I access the image.

> **NotSupportedException was unhandle by user code.** The given path's format is not supported.

The filename I use is like this:

```
\\10.10.1.123\shared\picture.jpg passwrd /USER:compname\userwithaccess
```

Where `passwrd` is the password of the user `userwithaccess` in the domain name of `compname`.

That path is working when I paste it in the Run, it opens the image, but why is it not working with `Image.FromFile` in my application?

---

<sup>My code is in C#, framework is in .NET 4.0. Project is a WCF Service, to be hosted in IIS, build on Visual Studio 2010 Pro.</sup>

Comment: "The given path's format is not supported."
Is that not self-explanatory?  Look at the string you are passing in... see anything that might cause the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at WindowsIdentity.Impersonate method.

[@ msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx)